# How to retrieve values in an object array in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have a problem with how to retrieve values in an object. In PropertyController I have this function:

```
public function getPropertyList()
{

  $properties = Property::where('properties.owner_id', Auth::guard('owner')->id())->get();

  foreach ($properties as $property){

     $items[] = array(
        'property' => $property,
        'images' => DB::table('property_photos')->where(['prop_id' => $property->prop_id,'is_default' => 1])->first()
     );

  }

  foreach ($items as $item){
     var_dump($item['property']->name); // This is working

     var_dump($item['images']->file_name); // Get error

  }
}
```

What I got from `$item['images']` is an object as follow:

```
object(stdClass)#324 (4) { 
   ["photo_id"]=> int(1) 
   ["prop_id"]=> int(2) 
   ["file_name"]=> string(45) "rD6ShpXA2mABPzdHsh7aTD66oRDK93SAHPLkaBSt.jpeg" 
   ["is_default"]=> int(1) 
} 
NULL 
NULL 
object(stdClass)#326 (4) { 
   ["photo_id"]=> int(4) 
   ["prop_id"]=> int(8) ["file_name"]=> string(45) "kzvBf1JTmeHAbdfQ30LwUGPYnQUummBjyqAVtgCn.jpeg" 
   ["is_default"]=> int(1) 
}
```

I have no problem retrieving `$items['property']` but I don't know how to retrieve the value of `file_name` in `$item['images']`. I tried using `$item['images']->file_name` but it get error `Trying to get property of non-object`.

Comment: Did you tried like this: `$item['images']['file_name'];`?

Comment: Try `$properties = Property::where('properties.owner_id', Auth::guard('owner')->id())->get()->toArray()`. It will return your object as array.

Comment: @DhananjayKyada the problem is how to get values in `$item['images']` not in `$item['property']`

Comment: please try `$item['images'][0]->file_name`

Comment: @dparoli still not working `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

Comment: Replace `DB::table('property_photos')->where(['prop_id' => $property->prop_id,'is_default' => 1])->first()` with `DB::table('property_photos')->where(['prop_id' => $property->prop_id,'is_default' => 1])->first()->toArray()`.
 Then you can use `$item['images']['file_name']`.

Comment: It seems you don't have value for some images. Thus it's an empty object and when you are trying to get the file_name of that object you are getting the error.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon yeah you're right. there're some rows with NULL values in file_name. so what I do make like `if ($item['images'] != NULL){ var_dump($item['images']->file_name); }` . Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You have empty objects in your $item['images']

Please try to use next:

```
$item['images']->file_name ?? 'default_value';
```